# Multiple users using spreadsheet without overwriting content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new and appreciate help on my question!

My spreadsheet acts as a sales tool, where info is entered in various cells to run sensitivity analysis. Once the salesperson picks a desired option they "submit it". The data submitted is then stored on a separate sheet in the spreadsheet (call it the "database").

I want the database sheet to store all user submissions. The problem is when multiple users are using the sales tool worksheet at the same time, the info they enter gets overwritten by other user's inputs before they can submit.

I'd like multiple users to be able to use the "sales tool" sheet simultaneously without overwriting eachother, but still be able to submit data to the "database" sheet.

Appreciate ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_lock) to take a lock on the spreadsheet and then release it once you've written to it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_lock) (already mentioned by Srik) there's the [Sheet.appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#appendRow) function, which is way easier to use and much faster. But only makes sense if you're inserting new data to a sheet and not really writing to the same cells.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a form? 
This way people could insert data without actually modify the spreadsheet...